# "Mono-Tabla" en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Primero que nada, un saludo a todos.

Tengo una duda acerca de la correcta o mejor manera de crear una tabla, así también para saber si existe algún tipo de regulación o reglas para este tipo de casos.

Mi duda surge al por ejemplo tener lo siguiente:

**a)**

[image: ER_1 de mi duda con tablas]

**b)**

[image: ER_2 de mi duda con tablas]

Como se muestran en los incisos, cual sería la manera optima o la mejor para mantener esos datos, asumiendo que una persona puede tener muchos medios de contacto, así también como que los tipos de contacto puedes ser variados, siendo estos por ejemplo: Telefono_1, Telefono_2, Correo electronico, Dirección, etc..

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, y si cuentan con algún tipo de fuente a la cual pueda recurrir para cosas similares a esta o de lineamentos para base de datos/SQL, les agradecería que las mencionasen también.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta puede estar basada en opiniones. Puede serte de interés leer [ask], ya que la misma puede no adaptarse al formato del sitio. [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinión lo mas correcto seria pasar el diagrama B a SQL en la mayoría de los casos.

El diseño de ese diagrama sería el mas correcto, ya que prácticamente siempre que accedas al contacto de una persona, también se va a acceder al tipo de contacto de esa persona. Por tanto, en las consultas, con la opción A, se estarían realizando muchas operaciones `JOIN`, lo que puede ralentizar el acceso a la base de datos y consumir mas recursos.

Solamente usaria la opcion A si:

- El tipo de contacto va a ser `NULL` en la mayoria (o muchas) ocasiones.
  (Si hay muchas entradas en la tabla, esto podría llegar a influir en el tamaño de la base de datos)
- Se prevee que TipoContacto tenga atributos propios no asociables a Persona, o se cree que en el futuro se van a añadir nuevos atributos. De esta forma, tipoContacto pasaría a ser una entidad propia, y sería mas fácilmente escalable

Como ves, cada opción tiene sus inconvenientes y beneficios, como casi todo a la hora de diseñar un programa, máquina, base de datos o cualquier otra cosa. Está bien tener reglas como referencia, pero a la hora de la verdad, la solución más óptima muchas veces depende del tipo de problema a resolver.

Para crear el atributo tipoContacto en caso de que escojas la opcion B, recomendaría usar un campo de tipo `ENUM`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Este tipo de datos permite definir un campo que solo puede tomar valores de una cierta lista. Por ejemplo:

```
tipoContacto ENUM('trabajo', 'amigos', 'equipo de futbol')
```

Solo permitiría a tipoContacto tomar los valores "trabajo", "amigos" o "equipo de futbol"